# Build project using LibGit2Sharp, have it run on .NET & Mono (Windows, Linux, Mac)

Tags: libgit2sharp

Using `LibGit2Sharp 0.22.0-pre20150606092322` (with NuGet), when I build my project on Windows, the NativeBinaries folder only includes .dll files, which I assume don't work on Linux (unless they're .NET libraries). Attempting to run the project on Linux causes an exception:

> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for LibGit2Sharp.Core.NativeMethods ---> System.DllNotFoundException: git2-ff8d635

I assume if I tried to build my project on Linux, it would contain the correct libraries, though no Windows ones. Is there a way I can build the project on one system and provide a download that works on all systems?

**edit:** Actually, I just built the project on Linux using MonoDevelop. The output does include a "packages" folder which contains a `.so` file in some sub-folder, but I still get the same exception if I just run it like that.

Comment: Could you please share a public repo url along with the repro steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Forgot to mention I used NuGet. Here's the repo: [copygirl/PackOPdater](https://github.com/copygirl/PackOPdater). Not sure about what you mean regarding repro steps. I simply build the project in Xamarin / MonoDevelop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using the latest prerelease LibGit2Sharp package, then you should also have a LibGit2Sharp.NativeBinaries package, which includes the native git2 libraries that LibGit2Sharp needs. In that package we include the following versions:

- 32-bit Windows (dll)
- 64-bit Windows (dll)
- 32 & 64-bit Mac (dylib), one file supports both architectures
- 64-bit Linux (so)

If you're trying to run on 32-bit linux, then there isn't a pre-built library included for that. What distro/architecture are you running?

When you install the LibGit2Sharp package, an MSBuild properties file is added to your project, and that is what handles copying the native binaries to the correct location as part of the build process.

If you're building on linux, then the build output should contain libgit2-ff8d635.so in the same directory as LibGit2Sharp.dll.

As long as your project isn't doing something that requires shadow copying your assemblies, that should be enough for mono to find and load the linux library.

If you are, for example if it's an asp.net project, then you have to make sure that the native linux library loader can find .so file, either by setting the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or actually installing it.

As far as building it once goes, since all of the pre-build native images are already sitting in the NativeBinaries package, your release process could include them directly from there.

Comment: Related discussion: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp.nativebinaries/issues/9

Comment: I tried building the project on my Arch laptop. It's actually run on a CentOS server though. When I built the project on Linux, it didn't output the `.so` to the same folder as the LibGit2Sharp .dll. I don't know much about MSBuild so I'll go read up on that, and probably accept the answer later then.

Comment: I'm looking your repo now, let me see if I can reproduce your problem!

Comment: For testing purposes, I uploaded the `libgit2-ff8d635.so` file included in the NativeBinaries package to my server (which is 64bit), and tried running it. Still throws a DllNotFoundException. Tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH too (launch script includes `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.`), but no idea if I did it correctly.

Comment: Looking at your repo, the .so and .dylib files aren't being put in the correct location on build. It's down inside a packages folder structure, which shouldn't be there. I just copied the .so file into the same folder as the .exe and it works for me. I'm looking into why that's happening now.

Comment: I've figured out why your project is having the weird copying behavior, and I'm working on a fix now: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp.nativebinaries/issues/10

Comment: I'm getting the same error, but on Windows while using Xamarin Studio. The MSBuild.properties file doesn't get created when the native binaries are installed. Is there documentation for creating it manually?